# Problema al crear o iniciar un proyecto de ionic en macos

Tags: nodejs, ionic, npm, unix

Estoy intentando instalar ionic en mi macbook, y he tenido un montón de problemas intentando instalar NODE y npm, al final he conseguido instalar todo sin error alguno, pero cuando trato de iniciar el proyecto, con este comando:

```
sudo ionic start ionicApp
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

    npm i exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
    information.
```

version de node: v8.11.4
version de npm: v6.4.1

He probado con todas las ayudas que te salen por consola, esta perfectamente instalado, y la verdad esto ya empieza a ser un dolor de cabeza mas que otra cosa. 
EDITO: 
He terminando formateando el pc, y he conseguido realizar la instalación sin ningún error, pero cuando trato de crear o iniciar un proyecto me sigue diciendo lo de 'permission denied' aun usando sudo en los comandos, 
El comando que uso es este: `sudo ionic start prueba` 
y el error que me tira es este:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Volumes/datos/Proyectos/ionicApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Volumes/datos/Proyectos/ionicApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/datos/Proyectos/ionicApp/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/davidpazolopez/.npm/_logs/2018-09-12T10_43_52_021Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

    npm i exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
    information.
```

Con lo cual no se que clase de problema puede existir con los permisos y npm pero sino tendre que probar a hacerlo con hombrew o con el manejador de npm.

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias anticipado...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @JackNavaRow ya lo he hecho, mismos errores. He googleado bastante y he desinstalado instalado todo, borrado cache, limpiado, ya no se que mas hacer pero no hay manera de montar un proyecto de ionic, incluso intento actualizar y me dice que sigo teniendo paquetes que no se actualizan

Comment: lo mismo.. gracias por tus aportes, he borrado too el node, y vuelto a instalar todo, me realizo la instalacion de ionic cordova y eso bien pero sigue con el cb() never called, y no me deja iniciar el proyecto.

Comment: Es la misma, 6.4.1. hable con el soporte de ionic tambien, posteare en el foro de node, porque no tiene sentido, que falle asi sin mas, ya que sigo todos los pasos de instalación desde 0..

Comment: lo ultimo que puedes hacer es darle upgrade a node y llevalo a la 10 node

Comment: como podria hacer eso? porque vi que podia usar npm -u pero no me va

Comment: esto me funciono para ubuntu no se si para mac, `sudo npm install -g n` `sudo n 10` y se debe ver la version `npm -v`

Comment: por cierto en tus pruebas desesperada de instalar una version posterior de node... tu borrastes la carpeta node_modules y volvistes a ejecutar el comando npm install?? debes hacerlo al actualizar una version de node npm o libreria global de node

Comment: SI, lo he borrado todo correctamente,  y luego lance el comando, probare eso a ver que pasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido solucionar activando el usuario root de mac,

Los pasos que he seguido son:

Preferencias del sistema->Usuarios y grupos->Acceder.. a servidor de cuentas de red, y en edición le das a activar usuario root.

Espero que pueda serle de ayuda a alguien mas que tenga problema similar, no es una solución, pero al menos ha solventado mi problema.

Saludos.