# Instalar y montar plantilla con npm

Tags: nodejs, npm, macos, pug

He comprado este template:

[https://pixinvent.com/bootstrap-admin-template/robust/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template/](https://themeforest.net/item/robust-responsive-bootstrap-4-admin-template-build-system/19297560)

https://themeforest.net/item/robust-responsive-bootstrap-4-admin-template-build-system/19297560

Y según pone la documentación aquí:

https://pixinvent.com/bootstrap-admin-template/robust/documentation/documentation-gulp.html

Necesito instalar node.js (o npm) y junto con gulp y jade puedo hacer una instalación completa del template.

Pero la verdad que tengo bastantes errores a la hora de intentar hacer `npm install` en el directorio del proyecto, tras pelearme con mac bastante conseguí instalar, node, npm, y gulp-cli de manera global. Pero a la hora de intentar generar el template me da este error:

```
32402 warn robust-admin-theme@1.2.0 license should be a valid SPDX 
license expression
32403 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
32404 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
32404 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
32405 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
32405 verbose optional Failed at the fsevents@1.2.7 install script.
32405 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
32406 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
32406 verbose stack Exit status 1
32406 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/davidpazolopez/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
32406 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
32406 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/usuario/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
32406 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
32406 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
32406 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
32407 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.11.0
32408 verbose cwd /Volumes/Datos/Proyectos/robust-admin-1.2
32409 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
32410 verbose argv "/Users/davidpazolopez/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/node" "/Users/davidpazolopez/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/npm" "install"
32411 verbose node v10.10.0
32412 verbose npm  v6.8.0
32413 error code ELIFECYCLE
32414 error errno 1
32415 error node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
32415 error Exit status 1
32416 error Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
32416 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
32417 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Mas que la solución a este error, porque por lo que veo es problema del modulo node-sass que no es capaz de encontrarlo y por lo que estuve viendo es cosa de node que no lo acepta, me gustaría que alguien que haya ha intentado hacer algo por el estilo, me guie o ayude para saber cuales son los pasos correctos que debería seguir para hacer la instalación correctamente, aparte de aprender a manejarme con Jade, y Node o npm.

Ante todo muchísimas gracias por su atención.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿No será algo parecido a lo que te pasó aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195416/problema-al-crear-o-iniciar-un-proyecto-de-ionic-en-macos/? 
¿Estás usando `npm` con `sudo`? A mi me ha pasado en linux alguna vez por eso

Comment: No, porque esta instalado todo correctamente, si hago el npm, node, o gulp -v me sale la version, ademas yo pregunto mas que por el error de npm o node, ya que entiendo que es culpa de mi ordenador, como hacer el montaje de la plantilla con jade y gulp porque la verdad la docu de la plantilla no me queda muy claro. Gracias por responder :)

Comment: Seguramente la plantilla venga  con un archivo un `gulpfile.js` que convierta los archivos `pug` (antes jade) en html y compile los archivos `sass` y ese tipo de cosas, no creo que tengas que hacer nada mientras no modifiques la plantilla, si cambias algo tendrás que lanzar `gulp` para que genere de nuevo los html, css, etc. Lo que te decía no tiene que ver con que esté mal instalado nada, solo que usando `sudo` o el usuario `root` en los comando `npm` muchas veces da errores, tambien puede ser algún conflicto entre versiones de node y npm